# What is the name of having two identical servers?

Tags: windows-sbs-2011, mirroring

I have a Windows Small Business Server 2011. I want to have another identical server (or mostly identical in hardware, thus identical in software). So, my email server, my users or anything else shall be identical on both server. I will have my main server (already existing) that copies on the fallback server. My webhoster (another company) will be set to transmit connections to the main server if available, otherwise, on the fallback one. So, a real-time sync is needed + an onload sync.

What is the name for this setup? And if you are able to answer, how may I do that? Is it only a matter of synchronizing files over internet?

Comment: SBS licensing doesn't allow for a hot-standby server. Thus the failover won't work as you'd probably expect since its a DC (Domain Controller). What resources (Websites, File Shares, DNS, etc) do you need in an HA (High Availability) configuration?

Comment: @user2320464 Exchange, Websites, Git server, other files. All the data of the services offered by the server so if it crash (like as a power failure), the other plays it role in the state the main was.

Comment: Best to research how to configure each of those services in HA since an SBS environment can have just a single Domain Controller (DC). AD can be extended to Azure though it has limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its called failover

here are few links that might help

http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-create-a-server-failover-solution/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731844(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the organizational impacts of keeping a service running is *business continuity*. A service made more reliable by running on multiple hosts is *highly available*. The verb to move a service around a *cluster* is *failing over*. A request able to be served by any of multiple hosts is *load balancing*.

Comment: Thank you for giving me more terms. Unfortunately I will keep the answer accepted to the first guy because he was already correct.